# Initial value of second solution of a 2nd-order ODE from Wronskian?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$ be two solutions of $(1-x^2)\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}-2x\dfrac{dy}{dx}+(\sec x)y=0$ with Wronskian $W(x)$. If $y_1(0)=1$, $\left(\dfrac{dy_1}{dx}\right)_{x=0}=0$ and $W(\frac12)=\frac13$, then $\left(\dfrac{dy_2}{dx}\right)_{x=0}$ equals?

I am having trouble in finding the value of $y_2'(0)$. I cannot compute $y_1$ and $y_2$ which I also don't want to find. I just want a method so as to use the provided information accurately to find $y_2'(0)$. I tried Abel's theorem but didn't know what to do with $x$ given to be two points; $W(1/2)$ is provided, but all other initial condition are given at $x=0$.

Comment: Abel's theorem tells you, given the ODE and the value of the Wronskian at some specific $x$ (not necessarily $x=0$!), how to construct the Wronskian for all $x$. So you'll want to start by doing just that.

Comment: i get w(x) = 1/4(1-x^2) . how shall now i proceed to find y2'(0) ? by the thanks for editing the question

Comment: You know the Wronskian for all $x$ now (and I get the same result). But you also can write down $W(x)$ in terms of $y_1,y_2$ and from this deduce the answer.

Comment: whoo..nice explanation, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hint 1: Abel's theorem tells you, given the ODE and the value of the Wronskian at some specific $x$ (not necessarily $x=0$!), how to construct the Wronskian for all $x$. Start by doing that.

Result:

> $W(x)=\dfrac{1}{1-4x^2}$

Hint 2: You now know the Wronskian for all $x$ now, and in particular at $x=0$. But you also can write down $W(0)$ in terms of $y_1,y_2$ at $x=0$ and from this deduce the answer.